# is it normal that Hot Reload VS 2022 rebuild my project?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, msbuild, hot-reload

I am new in .net core 6 because I just finished migrating my project.
I would like to know if this behavior is normal about the native hot reload in vs 2022.

I am on a .Net Core 6 Web App and when I modify a razor page while i'm running without debugging (ctrl +f5), the whole web project is rebuilt and this results in a reload of the application, which for me is not really a hot reload.

Did I miss something ? Or is it the normal behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43910), looks like a bug because my project configuration is not named "Debug"